# Infinite while loop when declaring a char variable with integer value

Tags: c

The code works fine if I declare `j` as `int` but it goes into infinite loop when I declare it as `char`.

```
char j=1;
while (j<=255){
    printf("%d ",j);
    j+=1;
}
```

Comment: A char will __always__ be `<=255`, it can't store bigger values.

Comment: Crank up your compiler warnings.  A good compiler will warn you that your test is always true, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/eYnEG43o3

Comment: Don't use `char` for your iterating variable, always use `int`, it's considered good practice.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: You're right, forgot about that - promotion to `int`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Tip: enable all warnings [@Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477539/infinite-while-loop-when-declaring-a-char-variable-with-integer-value/71484885#comment126335973_71477539) to save time and receive a warning like:

```
warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
```

---

Integer types in C have a **limed range**.

`char` has the same range as `signed char` or `unsigned char`, depending on the implementations uses *signed* or *unsigned* `char`.

Commonly `CHAR_MAX, SCHAR_MAX, UCHAR_MAX` are all 255 or less<sup>*1</sup>.  So comparing a `char <= 255` is always expected to be true.

```
char j=1;
while (j<=255){
  // Do something with j
}
```

---

**Advanced**

As code iterates, it does `j+=1;` which is like `j = j + 1;`.  Eventually this attempts to assign a value to `j` which is more than `CHAR_MAX`.  Assigning to an integer type a value outside its range leads to "either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised".  Commonly, the result is a "wrapped value" or `j` increments as 126, 127, -128, -127, ...

With `int j`, the range of an `int` is much larger and that wrap does not occur before the loop ends.  `j<=255` eventually becomes false, ending the loop.

---

<sup>*1</sup> Rare machines with more than 8-bits per `char` have greater range.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [this URL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm), a `char` only have one byte and hence, the value is between 0 and 255. If you add 1 to 255 (for a `char`), you just get 0 again. So your condition `j<=255` will always be met.

In case the meaning is that the range is between -128 and 127, then `127 + 1` gets calculated as -128.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: You're right. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Oops :-)